# Why does this perl code not produce a newline

Tags: perl, newline

I am working through some beginning examples of Perl.

```
print "\n6 less than 7 and 7 greater than 2 : ", 6 < 7 and 7 > 2, "\n";    
print ((3 + 2)/5), "\n";
```

The newlines at the end are not happening. Why?

Comment: Yeah I was just about to edit the code, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a matter of operator precedence. `and` has very low precedence, and should usually only be used for control flow. Perl will parse your code like this:

```
(print "\n6 greater than 7 and 7 greater than 2 : ", 6 < 7) and (7 > 2, "\n");    
(print +(3 + 2)/5), "\n";
```

The solutions:

- use `&&` instead of `and` when you intend to use the boolean operator
- alternatively, use parens to force certain precedence: `(6 < 7 and 7 > 2)`
- parens are also used for the argument list in a function call. If you don't want this interpretation, put a `+` before the parens:

  ```
  print +((3 + 2)/5), "\n";
  ```

  is the same as

  ```
  print( ((3 + 2)/5), "\n" );
  ```
- use the `say` function instead of `print`, as `say` automatically appends a newline:

  ```
  use feature 'say';
  say +(3 + 2)/5;
  ```

Comment: You could also add the using `strict` and `warnings` the OP could have got useful hints... (I just though that it would be better to have it here instead of adding another answer)

Comment: Oh so that's how you use the feature `say`.